# How does event bubbling/ capturing affect e.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

edit: For new viewers of the question, my title is misleading. The solution to this problem had nothing to do with event bubbling/capturing as was my assumption at the time of posting.

I have a mobile navigation menu that contains 3 `<li>` elements which, when clicked, `toggleSlide()` a dropdown menu. The jQuery code for each of them is largely the same:

```
const coreSlider = function() {
     const aContainer = document.querySelector('#dropdown-A');
     const aLinks = document.querySelector('#A-links');
     const dontOpen = document.querySelector('.mob-prev-def');
        
     $(aContainer).on('click', function() {
          $(aLinks).slideToggle(200);
     });

     $(dontOpen).on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
     });
}
...
```

Above is an example of the jQuery code on 1 of these dropdown containers, and behaves exactly as I want it to (toggles the drop-down menu on click, but does not redirect to the href value inside the `<li>` inside the container. However, I still want the links that appear on click to direct them to the relevant part of my website.

There are 2 more containers with jQuery code exactly like this, but for whatever reason the `e.preventDefault()` part of the code on them doesn't work as intended, and redirects on click. I figure that event bubbling/ capturing has something to do with it, but I'm not sure how exactly it is functioning in this example. To that end, what's going on here and how can I fix it to ensure all containers behave as I want? Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="nav-links">
          <li id="dropdown-A">
                <a href="vot-A.html" class="mob-prev-def" type="text/html">...</a>

          <div id="A-links">
                <a href="vot-A.html">...</a>
                <a href="vot-B.html">...</a>
                <a href="vot-C.html">...</a>
          </div>
     </li>

     <li id="dropdown-D">
          <a href="vot-D.html" class="mob-prev-def" type="text/html">...</a>

          <div id="D-links">
                <a href="vot-D.html">...</a>
                <a href="vot-D-i.html">...</a>
                <a href="vot-D-ii.html">...</a>
                <a href="vot-D-iii.html">...</a>
          </div>
     </li>

     <li id="dropdown-E">
          <a href="vot-E.html" class="mob-prev-def" type="text/html">...</a>

          <div id="E-links">
                <a href="vot-E-i.html">...</a>
                <a href="vot-E-ii.html">...</a>
          </div>
     </li>
            
     <li id="gallery"><a href="vot-gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Edit: thanks to user Stone3m, I managed to add in a solution:

```
const prevDef = function() {
     const dontOpen = $('.mob-pref-dev');

     $(dontOpen).on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
     });
}

prevDef();
```

Comment: Why are you mixing DOM API and jQuery?

Comment: I haven't got round to studying the pros and cons of using vanilla JS over jQuery and vice-versa yet. I've found useful stuff in both, so as part of my experimentation in my first dev project I've been using both. I'm acutely aware that this isn't a good idea but I haven't got round to the tidy-up yet - very much at the point where I'm trying to figure out what works then do the tidy-up later.

Comment: `$(dontOpen)` should really be `dontOpen`. No need to wrap a jQuery object ***again***. Aside from that, I really recommend preferring the DOM API over any third party code like jQuery any day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using querySelector, which only selects one occurrence.
You should be using querySelectorAll with a forEach loop for every occurrence.

A quick and simple method would be to:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mob-prev-def').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
})
```

Sorry, I prefer vanilla JavaScript, but you could figure it out in jQuery now (I hope!)

Comment: Amost always a bad idea mixing the DOM API and jQuery. Well spotted!

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Stone3m! This resolved my issue. I took what you posted and converted it into jQuery. I'll edit the jQuery solution into the end of the question.